# What's the difference between context.map_query and qry.map_async in Appengine's NDB?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, asynchronous, app-engine-ndb

The documentation seems to suggest that they can be used similarly. What is the difference and when should each be used? Which should be used for optimum performance (as both suggest that they are the "fastest").

Documentation for context.map_query: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rPyB2RmRERAZDPpqy2cxzXeDGyfLhX-s-3dFVpnwFXw/edit?hl=en_US#heading=h.wniiq5a4ja4o

Documentation for qry_obj.map_async: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rPyB2RmRERAZDPpqy2cxzXeDGyfLhX-s-3dFVpnwFXw/edit?hl=en_US#heading=h.t1t6424hbp7y

Comment: Guido replied himself at http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=130&can=1&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use qry_obj.map_async(). Context().map_query() is a lower-level API that you shouldn't need. Note, that document is way out of date; I have a TODO to update it but other things keep getting priority. Fortunately the Google App Engine documentation team is helping out with documentation now.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/query.py#918) it appears `Query.map_async` is just a shortcut to call `Context.map_query`:

```
def map_async(self, callback, merge_future=None, **q_options):
   """Map a callback function or tasklet over the query results.

   This is the asynchronous version of Query.map().
   """
   return tasklets.get_context().map_query(self, callback,
                                           options=_make_options(q_options),
                                           merge_future=merge_future)
```